# Convolution of two pdf

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, histogram, convolution

The pdf of the sum of two random variables, x and y, is given by the convolution of the individual pdfs. In the following code, I read single columns data from each file and show the histograms. How can I compute the convolution of pdf1 and pdf2.

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', header=None)

data2 = pd.read_csv('file2.txt', header=None)

nbins = int(data1.max()-data1.min())

pdf1 = plt.hist(data1, bins=nbins, normed=True)


nbins = int(data2.max()-data2.min())

pdf2 = plt.hist(data2, bins=nbins, normed=True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use `scipy.signal.convolve` to compute the convolution between two series. Look at the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html).

Do as follows :

```
from scipy.signal import convolve

# Define your arrays of data
pdf_1 = plt.hist(data1, bins=nbins, normed=True)
pdf_2 = plt.hist(data2, bins=nbins, normed=True)

# Convolve the two arrays
pdf_1_2 = convolve(pdf_1, pdf_2, mode="valid")
```

**NB :** You have access to other modes to compute the convolution. The `valid` mode is absed on zero-padding.

Comment: Thank you. As you mentioned, convolve() works on arrays but pdf_1 and pdf_2 are tuples. convolve(pdf_1[0], pdf_2[0]) works but it only gives the y-axis values and not whole histogram.

Comment: @kiasari of what value would the x-axis values `hist[1]` be when calculating the convolution, given that they are just the bins? the y-axis values are the non-negative probability values generated by `plt.hist(data1, bins=nbins, normed=True)[0]` which would have priority as inputs into `convolve`, since they essential *are* the probability distribution, not the x-axis bins, right